# How to get a heart filled of black color in katex?

Tags: katex

What I know/I tried so far:

1. `\spadesuit` or `\spades` renders spade with filled black color.
2. Similarly, `\clubs` or `\clubsuit` renders club with filled black color.
3. Now `\hearts` or `\heartsuit` just renders heart with white filled bg.
4. `\colorbox` treats this as a box/rectangle, thus hiding the shape obviously.
5. I can get black diamond as `\blacklozenge`

[Please see this in new tab](https://katex.org/?data=%7B%22displayMode%22%3Atrue%2C%22leqno%22%3Afalse%2C%22fleqn%22%3Afalse%2C%22throwOnError%22%3Atrue%2C%22errorColor%22%3A%22%23cc0000%22%2C%22strict%22%3A%22warn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22htmlAndMathml%22%2C%22trust%22%3Afalse%2C%22macros%22%3A%7B%22%5C%5Cf%22%3A%22%231f(%232)%22%7D%2C%22code%22%3A%22%5C%5Cspades%5Cn%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cspadesuit%5Cn%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cclubs%5Cn%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cclubsuit%5Cn%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cn%5C%5Chearts%5Cn%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cheartsuit%22%7D)

Also, I get it that `club and spade are black` and the `diamonds and heart are red` in a deck, but I want heart symbol in black as well.

How can I get that? Thanks.

Asked on github too : https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/discussions/2546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits and thanks to : [Ronkok](https://github.com/ronkok)

> KaTeX \hearts and \heartsuit render a heart outline, ♡, U+2661, , so they do not help you. The Unicode character for a filled heart is ♥, U+2665. That glyph is not in the KaTeX fonts, but you can still use it and KaTeX will substitute the glyph from the Times New Roman system font.

> KaTeX emulates LaTeX, and this is not a LaTeX function, so KaTeX will write at least one error to the console (two if in strict mode). If you don't mind a console error, then no worries. KaTeX does render the heart. **Just copy ♥ and paste it into your work.**

Until there is any further update, this is what'll we have to work with guys.